# scala client/server library for simple game (battleships)

Tags: scala, client, server

I am planning to make a multiplayer battleships game in scala, so that people could connect to the server and play together, and I was trying to (but failed) find a nice library for simple and scala idiomatic library to make this client - server communication, it would be nice to pass some kind of objects, not text or something. Can anyone suggest this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need RPC client/server system, I would suggest to take one of these two:

1. [Finagle](https://finagle.github.io/blog/) - super flexible and powerful RPC client/server from Finagle. You can define your service with Thrift, and it will generate stubs for client/server in scala. With Thrift it should be straightforward to add Python support.
2. [Spray](http://spray.io) - much smaller library, focused on creating REST services. It's not so powerful as Finagle, however much easier. And REST allows you to use any other clients

Comment: it seems hell of a complicated for me atm. I found kryonet for java that seems very easy and does all I need but it's not scala. You think there is something similar for scala?